# long polling with iframe not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, polling

I'm trying to build an IRC chat application for a live streaming site. For each live video there will ba a live channel and the user will automatically joined to the respective channel. I'm using iframe long polling for this. The iframe will push the javascript content to the browser. The problem is it is not working correctly in IE, when multiple live videos are taken in different tabs. It shows waiting to complete the first iframe script and the page will not load correctly. Please help me!.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the frames names depend on the video id or something else that's unique for a tab.